# Random crash using a 'for' loop

Tags: c++

I've just picked up C++ and I've just finished a little bit of code for an excersise. The problem is, this code runs indefinitely. Could one of you explain why? The idea is to produce a table of characters and their corresponding integers, this for a-z, A-Z, and 1-100.

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{

    for (char table_value_lower = 'a'; table_value_lower <= 'z'; ++table_value_lower)
        cout << table_value_lower << '\t' << int(table_value_lower) << '\n';
    for (char table_value_upper = 'A'; table_value_upper <= 'Z'; ++table_value_upper)
        cout << table_value_upper << '\t' << int(table_value_upper) << '\n';
    for (char table_value_integer = '0'; table_value_integer <= '100'; ++table_value_integer)
        cout << table_value_integer << '\t' << int(table_value_integer) << '\n';

}
```

Comment: `'100'` that's not a `char`. It is a multibyte char, if it is supported on your system

Comment: Random crash != runs indefinitely

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `'0'` to `'9'`?

Answer (score 3):

This is your problem:

```
for (char table_value_integer = '0'; table_value_integer <= '100'; ++table_value_integer)
    cout << table_value_integer << '\t' << int(table_value_integer) << '\n';
```

The closest you can come to what you're doing would be this:

```
for (char table_value_integer = '0'; table_value_integer <= '9'; ++table_value_integer)
    cout << table_value_integer << '\t' << int(table_value_integer) << '\n';
```

In the [ASCII character set](http://ascii-table.com/ascii.php) the character `'0'` has the value 48 (0x30). If you increment that you get 49, which is the character `'1'`, then 50, which is the character `'2'` and so forth until you get to 57, which is the character `'9'`. When you increment it again you get 58, which is the character `':'`. It will never become `'10'` as you seem to think. You can't make two characters by incrementing a single character.

If you really want to increment it to 100, then you would do this:

```
for (char table_value_integer = '0'; table_value_integer <= 100; ++table_value_integer)
    cout << table_value_integer << '\t' << int(table_value_integer) << '\n';
```

The value 100, by the way, is the character `'d'`. Look at the ASCII chart I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

`table_value_integer <= '100'` doesn't make sense. If you want to go to 100, use `100` (no quotes): `table_value_integer <= 100`.

With the quotes, it is a multi-byte character or nothing defined, and you are checking against something different than you expect.

Also, you probably want `char table_value_integer = 0;` (and not `'0'`)

Comment: No, `'100'` is still not a string, but `"100"` would be, with double quotes.